# A-level electromagnetism experiments?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, soft-question, resource-recommendations

Does anybody know any A-level experiments investigating electromagnetism that can produce good data relatively simply?

Comment: There are some here, myself included, who don't know what "A-level" means.

Comment: This question (v3) seems like a list question.

Comment: @KyleKanos I believe it refers to the British schooling system to a type of level of classes. I think it would be similar or equivalent to AP's in the USA.

Comment: And what about those of us who don't know what AP is either?

Comment: @JavierBadia last year of high school. Now, if anyone *dares* to mention 'people who don't know what high school is'... ;-)